# How many Alphas are there?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

In the movie Tom kills an Alpha and gets the Alpha’s powers. I have two questions:

1. Is it ever mentioned how many Alphas there are? (We see Emily kill one as well.)
2. Do they ever discuss the possibility of actively searching for other Alphas to reproduce the effect?

Comment: Found a reference to the amount of Alphas with respect to normal mimics (http://www.quora.com/Was-the-number-of-Beta-to-Alpha-mimics-the-arms-mimics-to-the-central-nervous-mimics-a-deliberate-reference-to-the-golden-ratio), stating 1 Alpha to every 618 million mimics, but without knowing how many normal mimics there were, the first question can't be answered. As for the second question, I can't remember it being discussed and can't find a reference, but I remember the assumption being that the Alphas are simply too rare to try to find, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Plus, nobody believed them about the time-travel. They wouldn't try to reproduce something they don't believe in when the risk is great.

Comment: Im thinking more along the lines Tom/Emily finding another Alpha frst. Then getting itno a position and exterminating it in close proximity to a squad of soldiers. 
NOT thinking of them going up the chain of command as that is POINTLESS!!

Comment: @Cherubel extrapolating from that question - how would the whole "reset the day" thing work if both of them got covered in the Alphas blood and gained the power?

Comment: Possible spoilers? Movies pretty old at this stage I suppose.

Comment: @Moo, it might work like it does with multiple Alphas...if any of them die, the day is reset. Just a guess. They didn't really know how it worked in the first place either.

Comment: If we assume the population of mimics is roughly equal to the number of humans, then the number of alphas would be... roughly twelve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based off of the original book/light novel, I don't have an answer to the first one — the only data we get is that they encounter two Alphas in the course of the history of the book — but I can answer that they did not discuss looking for more Alphas because

> There can only be one person empowered to send a message back to the past to change the future. If there's more than one, then the Mimics will always be able to have future knowledge and counter the humans. That's why Keiji and Rita had to fight to the death before killing the Alpha the final time.